# How to test with Vitest in Vue 3 Suspense wrapper?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vitest

I tried a lot of techniques like
await flushPromises();

or

await nextTick();

or

component.vm.nextTich()

Nothing works!

Answer (score 0):

In tests Vitest just worked with components wrapped in

just setTimeout!!!

For example in some.spec.ts file:

```
describe("Page", () => {
      it("should do something", async () => {
        setTimeout(  () => {
            const something = component.find('.wrap');
            expect(something).toExist();
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Self-answers are welcome on SO but the same quality requirements are applicable to them. The question should conform https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and not be a prompt for an answer. It's a bad practice to put random timeouts in code without control over execution. A test like this won't work as intended because test runner is unaware of async operations that occur outside the promise chain, this test will always pass. If you have asynchronous operations that take more time than flushPromises, you need to mock or spy a promise that's responsible for a delay and wait for it

Comment: If it'is a bad practice to setTimeout(), please, offer another solution. Working solution. No? So that's it for the moment. If you offer better solution you are welcome. If you just want to say your 'fe' - it's not the deal.

Comment: Users may be able to suggest better solutions if the question is asked properly, that's the idea. Currently only you know your case and why setTimeout worked but not anything else. And it didn't actually worked as noted above, it's false positive, try to make expect() fail to make sure, it's expected to output an error but the test will pass